# Create drop down list which will show the first item from the drop down menu when it is generated Using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a drop down list in google sheet using google app script.
Sheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TESZNYgSJC-ye8r9CcW57-Vt1yU5VcvELiJw4oRwAZQ/edit#gid=0

In this sheet, in column B there is responsible person. Whenever I will select any name from the drop down list of this column, the another drop down list will create in column C and in column D the current date will appear. For example, If I select 'Anushka' in cell B2, a drop down list 'New', 'on going', 'done', 'on hold' will create in cell C2 with the first value from the list of the drop down and a current date will appear in cell D2.
Till now, I can create the drop down menu in cell C2 and also  current date in cell D2 based one cell B2. But I don't know how to show always the first item from the drop down list in cell C2. Now it's giving me blank cell and I need to select something from the menu but I want in a way that when drop down menu will create, it will show the first item not empty cell.
I have attached the code also.
Can anyone please help me where I should modify?

```
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var colrange=sheet.getRange("B2:B").isBlank()
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var cindex = actRng.getColumnIndex();

   if(colrange){
    sheet.getRange(index,4).clearContent()
    sheet.getRange(index,3).clearDataValidations()
   } else{
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"EST", "MMMM-dd-yyyy");
    var list=["New", "Ongoing", "Done", "On-Hold"]

    var rule=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).build()
    sheet.getRange(index,3).setDataValidation(rule)
    sheet.getRange(index,4).setValue(date)
   }
```

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Please provide the input data and the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Validations

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.value) {
    e.source.toast("Flag1");
    let rg = e.source.getRangeByName("Status");
    e.range.offset(0,1).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(rg));
    e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(new Date());
    Logger.log(e.source.getRangeByName("Status").getValues()[0][0])
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(e.source.getRangeByName("Status").getValues()[0][0]);
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Named Ranges:

[image]

In answer to your comment below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast("Flag1");
    let rg = e.source.getRangeByName("Status");
    e.range.offset(0,1).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(rg));
    e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(new Date());
    //Logger.log(e.source.getRangeByName("Status").getValues()[0][0])
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(e.source.getRangeByName("Status").getValues()[0][0]);
  }
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && !e.value) {
    //e.source.toast("Flag2");
    let rg = e.source.getRangeByName("Status");
    e.range.offset(0,1).clearDataValidations();
    e.range.offset(0,2).setValue('');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, Thanks a lot for solving the problem. I need to change the getRangebyName to getRange. Now it's working. Thank you so much for the help. By the way, do you know what I can add here that if I remove the entry from Column 2 for example if the cell is blank then the corresponding rows will become empty again?

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for quick response and again helping me. It worked exactly the same way I wanted. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hi Cooper, I want to add a column of email address in the sheet. I want to automate the email address in way that when the name is selected in the column B, the email address of that name will generate in the column E for example. I have the drop down list of the email address. When one select Bob. the email address of Bob will appear. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Probably where do the emails originate?

Comment: In the above sheet, in the tab People I have added email address beside the Name column. Now In the sheet1, when I will select name from the responsible person, the email address of this person will generate to the email address column. I know how to do it with VLOOKUP but i want to add this in the script. Link of the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TESZNYgSJC-ye8r9CcW57-Vt1yU5VcvELiJw4oRwAZQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hi Coper, I think I am going to use Vlookup. won't use script for this